# Python - print split line starting at the n-th element

Tags: python, list, split, line

I have a string as the result of a line.split from a file.
How can I write this string to another file starting by the 5th element?

EDIT:
I got this and it works:

```
for line in data.readlines ()
if not line.startswith ("H"):
s = line.split ()
finaldata.write (" ".join (s [5:]))
finaldata.write ("\n")
```

The only problem is that i have some empty "cells" in my input and that is messing the output (shifting the data to the left where i the original input has a blank)

How can i do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You know how to `split` the string, right? Do you know how to slice a list, like `lst[1:]` to get everything after the first element? From those two, you should be able to figure out the answer here.

Comment: Find and replace _what_?

Comment: Don't even need to split, just `print(s[s.index('e'):])` although you should use a numeric index if your letters repeat.

Comment: @chrisz That will only work if every one of his strings is `"a b c d e f g h"`—in which case it would be simpler to just `print("e f g h")`.

Comment: I have a string s=line.split () , i don't know how to use slice to print s elements starting from the 4th one. I also want to find elements "A1" and "R1" and replace these elements with "P1" and "2"

Comment: If you know the element by count you should slice the string. string[5:] would print the 5th character to the end of the line.

Comment: But what is the syntax for slicing?

Comment: So the slicing has a pretty basic syntax; lets say you have a string a = "a b c d e f g h". you can slice "a" from the 5th character like this a[5:] outputs ' d e f g h'.  Slicing syntax is [start:end:step] .  so [5:] says start at 5 and include the rest.  There are a ton of examples here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question: If you know the element by count you should slice the string. string[5:] would print the 5th character to the end of the line. Slicing has a pretty basic syntax; lets say you have a string

```
a = "a b c d e f g h"
```

You can slice "a" from the 5th character like this

```
>>> a[5:] 
' d e f g h'
```

Slicing syntax is [start:end:step] . so [5:] says start at 5 and include the rest. There are a ton of examples here [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

The second question isn't exactly clear what you're trying to achieve... Here are some examples of common standard string manipulations with inline comments

```
>>> a = "a b c d e f g h"
>>> a[5] # Access the 5th element of list using the string index
' '  
>>> a[5:] # Slice the string from the 5th element to the end
' d e f g h'  
>>> a[5::2] # Get every other character from the 5th element to the end
'     '
>>> a[6::2] # Get every other character from the 6th element to the end
'defgh'
# Use a list comprehension to remove all spaces from a string
>>> "".join([char for char in a if char != " "]) 
'abcdefgh'
# remove all spaces and print from the fifth character
>>> "".join([char for char in a if char != " "])[5:] 
'fgh'
>>> a.strip(" ") # Strip spaces from the beginning and end
'a b c d e f g h' 
>>> a[5:].strip(" ")  # slice and strip spaces from both sides
'd e f g h'
>>> a[5:].lstrip(" ")  # slice and use a left strip
'd e f g h'
```

Edit: To add in a comment from another user. if you know the character rather than the position, you can slice from that. Though, if you have duplicate characters you'll have to be careful.

```
>>> a[a.index("e"):] # Slice from the index of character
'e f g h'
>>> b = "a e b c d e f g h e"
>>> b[b.index("e"):]
'e b c d e f g h e'
```